# System.Windows.Controls ChildWindow for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is any replacement for ChildWindow from System.Windows.Controls for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight? I need to implement custom popup window.

Before on Windows Phone 8.0 project it was implemented in this way:

http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2011/06/how-to-create-childwindow-login-popup.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup)  control and take advantage of IsOpen property of the control.